# Expand arrays from a stream of JSON values of various types

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to parse to JSON from the variable below:

When I call my variable like this: *echo $IDS | jq*

I receive:

```
"/redfish/v1/Chassis"
"/redfish/v1/$metadata#ChassisCollection.ChassisCollection"
"#ChassisCollection.ChassisCollection"
"ChassisCollection"
[
   {
    "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Chassis/14"
   },
   {
     "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Chassis/9"
   },
   {
     "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Chassis/1"
   },
   {
     "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Chassis/25"
   },
   {
     "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Chassis/5"
   },
   {
     "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Chassis/26"
   },
   {
     "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Chassis/6"
   },
   {
     "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Chassis/22"
   }
]
28
```

When I then try to extract all the chassis ID's I cannot get them without error:

*IDT=$(echo $IDS | jq '.[][]')*

returns:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over string ("/redfish/v...)
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over string ("/redfish/v...)
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over string ("#ChassisCo...)
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over string ("ChassisCol...)
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over number (28)
```

even when I use

*IDT=$(echo $IDS | jq -R '.[][]')*

it returns

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over string ("\"/redfish...)
```

I do end up with a variable $IDT with exactly what I want in it, but I need to achieve this without getting any errors along the way:

Result of  *echo $IDT | jq*

```
"/redfish/v1/Chassis/14"
"/redfish/v1/Chassis/9"
"/redfish/v1/Chassis/1"
"/redfish/v1/Chassis/25"
"/redfish/v1/Chassis/5"
"/redfish/v1/Chassis/26"
"/redfish/v1/Chassis/6"
"/redfish/v1/Chassis/22"
```

Who knows how to achieve my goal without getting errors along the way? All help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Select arrays and apply **.[][]** to only them.

```
select(type == "array") .[][]
```

Or, shorter:

```
arrays[][]
```

Comment: The best of both worlds :-)